# Mapping without polluting the original operator

Tags: key-bindings

Sometimes in a diff I want to obtain just the single line that I'm on. So I made the following mappings:

```
nnoremap dO :.diffget<CR>
nnoremap dP :.diffput<CR>
```

This worked well, *except* now whenever I do `dd` it sits and waits for more input since the last `d` could be the start of one of my new mappings. Now, of course I *could* just change my mappings to something different to solve this problem, but this means that I can't use **any** of the `d` namespace that [isn't currently being used](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2014/02/follow-my-leader/) which is quite unfortunate. I want vim to understand that I'm simply trying to extend the `d` namespace. `dd` is a finished command and `ddO` is invalid, therefore there is no need to wait after `dd` has been entered. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I do not see why your mappings would cause a delay after `dd`. I have tested your mappings and I see no delay with `dd`. Are you sure you do not have another set of conflicting mappings? Use `:verbose nmap dd` to see all `dd` related mappings.

Comment: @PeterRincker Before I put the mapping, `dd` works as expected. After the mapping `dd` pauses for a few seconds before acting. `:verbose nmap dd` reports "No mapping found." I have noticed after some experimentation that when set from my `.vimrc` I experience this problem, but when I set it straight from an ex command it works as you've described. Not sure why there would be a disconnect there, but honestly the wait seems like expected behavior to me.

Comment: There should be no difference between defining the commands in your `vimrc` or via an ex command. I was able to successfully test your mappings in my `vimrc` without a delay. If you are still experiencing a delay then I must assume there is something in your `vimrc` that is causing the issue. I would suggest you start with a bare vimrc or at the very least comment out portions of your `vimrc` until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're referring to as a "namespace" is an `operator`.  When you press `d`, you are put in `Operator-pending` mode.  That is, the operator is waiting for a key (typically a motion to define a range) before executing their respective commands, such as `:delete`.

You can change your maps to operator maps:

```
onoremap <expr> O v:operator == 'd' ? ':.diffget<cr>' : '<esc>'
onoremap <expr> P v:operator == 'd' ? ':.diffput<cr>' : '<esc>'
```

Operator maps aren't usable until you're in `Operator-pending` mode.  That means that the maps above could be used with *all* operators.  But you only want it to work with `d`, so check to see if the pending operator is `d` before allowing `O` and `P` to be used for the diff commands.  Using another operator such as `cO` would return `<esc>` cancelling the operator.

Operator maps can be more complicated than this.  Read `:h omap-info`, `:h 'operatorfunc'`, `:h v:operator` and `:h g@` to learn more about them.

Comment: Oh, clever! I thought of answering and suggesting `onoremap`, but I didn't know how to make it only apply to `d`, and not all the other operators. Thanks, I learned something very useful today!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem If you want to see elaborate operator maps, check out [fakeclip.vim](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip/blob/master/plugin/fakeclip.vim) and [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/plugin/surround.vim).  Search for `g@` in the source.

Comment: Sweet! Yes, I was tentatively looking at `onoremap` as well, but have never used it before and wasn't sure how to go about it. Thanks!